# Which sorting algorithm used in thrust::sort?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am interested in thrust::sort implementation.
Which sorting algorithm is used? Is it used all power of gcc and which kind of parallelism is there?

Comment: I believe the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037906/fast-cuda-thrust-custom-comparison-operator) is still accurate, as it was written by one of the authors of Thrust.  Since that answer was written, for the first case (the fast case) thrust has moved to using a sort implementation provided by [cub](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_radix_sort.html), but as far as I know it is still radix sort.  It's not difficult to prove this with a bit of effort from one of the CUDA profilers.

Comment: thrust uses radix sort if the data is numerical and default comparator. or else it uses merge sort. https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/4fd1b54cece96c56e49d6a3fc8df6c4ab1c9499c/thrust/system/cuda/detail/sort.h#L1505

Answer (score 3):

Thrust uses a Radix sort. Even though the manual page redirects to an old SGI page, apparently this is not to be taken to mean that the SGI page is authoritative as to the algorithm.  Documentation on the Radix sort can be found [here](https://mgarland.org/files/papers/gpusort-ipdps09.pdf).